# How to run JS code used by Google on my computer?

Tags: javascript

## 1. Why

I like Google's [snake game](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=snake+game&oq=snake+game&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i61j69i60l3j69i61j69i60.871j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), there's many cool effects in there. I want to learn how it's done by reading the source code.

## 2. What I did so far

I managed to find the [source code](https://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.KbC43pj83qc.O/ck=xjs.s.oso18Jaj3Hw.L.W.O/am=AAAAAABAAAAAwBKwdweQ478JgLtgEwcAAAAAEsAlQWOBFEJCQQACAAAAZ7UEQYAC/d=1/exm=IvlUe,MC8mtf,TJw5qb,Y33vzc,ZyRBae,cdos,csi,d,hsm,iDPoPb,jsa,mvYTse,tg8oTe/ed=1/dg=2/br=1/ct=zgms/rs=ACT90oEziF6sZEkD6sfZiJ4rNOX6yMPL6g/m=Adromf,E2Spzb,IkchZc,MB3mMb,MkHyGd,NBZ7u,OG6ZHd,PXJ3Gf,RMhBfe,RqxLvf,Ru9aL,SvnKM,T7XTS,TxZWcc,URQPYc,V9u9Nb,VMAidf,VhENbf,WsHJSc,XMgU6d,XjCeUc,aCZVp,aa,aam1T,abd,async,bgd,dvl,eN4qad,eT9j9d,fEVMic,foot,gpo5Gf,i28xR,iD8Yk,kyn,lli,lu,m,m3WqZc,m6a0l,mUpTid,mu,nTzqEc,o02Jie,pB6Zqd,qik19b,rHjpXd,runuse,sSWo2e,sb_wiz,sf,sonic,spch,tl,uE6Wcc,uiNkee,vs,wft,wkrYee,wrFDyc,xiqEse,xz7cCd,zbML3c?xjs=s1) (by searching the jsname of the canvas), but it's very hard for me to read. The code was minified, and I even don't know where's does the execution start.

## 3. What do I want

I hope someone can tell me how to run it on my computer, or give me some articles about it.

Comment: maybe you can copy the code and unminify it

Answer (score 1):

Well it is technically already running on your computer since JS is executed client-side

Although if you don't want to run it on the site itself you can download the resources it uses and run it locally, you may have to change the URL's where it looks for the resources in the HTML though. Although I don't really see the point in doing this as both run the js on your computer so it will function the same unless you are planning on editing the js.

In terms of the code being minified, both firefox and chrome have a nice prettify button built into their dev tools. Shown below is an example of the firefox one, just click that.
[image]
Although I have no idea what your skill level is. If you are very new to js, I think starting with more traditional resources would make learning a lot faster and less frustrating, then you can come back to this later.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're going to run into is Google runs their scripts through their own [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler) so the code isn't just minified, but optimized and much more difficult to read.

The best you can do to better understand the code is run the code through a [beautifier](https://beautifier.io/) to have it formatted a bit nicer for you to then go through line by line, renaming variables and functions as you figure out what they do.

If you're simply looking to run it locally, you could save the resources used and run the local files in a browser. [HTTrack Website Copier](http://www.httrack.com/) is a nice tool to localize all resources for a website. In this instance just be sure to do the single page (it can also crawl and save an entire site). Google will block you very quickly if you start automatically crawling/copying their pages (even by accident) as this is understandably against their terms.

Comment: OK, thank you! I will try what you mentioned!